# What are the uses/applications of Single precision Floating point numbers?

Tags: floating-point-precision

I'm doing a project on single precision floating numbers. I was wondering in what fields or areas are these concepts used? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you don't need double precision and memory is precious.

Comment: Did you do any research before posting this?

Comment: Yeah, I's done some research regarding this, but still had a small element of doubt, was a little unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anything requiring larger range than available with integers, and where limited accuracy of number representation isn't important enough to use longer floats. In terms of accuracy, nothing beats integer or fixed point, at the price of their limited range. Say if i wanted cosmological distances in a unit which can be used for both nearer and far objects at the same time, i could think of using those - after all, i'd be mostly interested in the most significant parts of the distance, not in the submillimeter portion.